# Spring query distinct on a entire object

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm using spring data and I made this query:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT u.pk.fleet.fleetName FROM FleetHasUser u WHERE u.pk.user.username = ?1")
List<FleetName> allFleetNameForUser(String username);
```

The aim of this query is find all FleetName for a specific user.
This is the part of database schema interested in:
[image]

The `FleetHasUser` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fleet_has_user", catalog = "dart")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_username")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.fleet", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_fleet")) })
public class FleetHasUser implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private FleetHasUserKeys pk = new FleetHasUserKeys();
    
    
    @EmbeddedId
    public FleetHasUserKeys getPk() {
        return pk;
    }
```

the `FleetHasUserKeys` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class FleetHasUserKeys implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected User user;
    protected Fleet fleet;
```

`Fleet` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fleet", catalog = "dart")
public class Fleet implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer idFleet;
    private Ecu ecu;
    private String application;
    private Cubic cubic;
    private Integer power;
    private String euroClass;
    private String engineType;
    private Traction traction;
    private String transmission;
    private String note;
    private FleetName fleetName;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>(0);
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<FleetHasUser> fleetHasUsers = new HashSet<FleetHasUser>(0);
```

As you can see FleetName is a class. I tried without distinct and the list had duplicated elements, so before create a subquery I inserted distinct only for test and it worked. I didn't find information on google, but is it possible to use distinct on a object? How does it work(check the primary key fields)?

Maybe may I even create a Spring data query like `findDistinctPkFleetFleetNameByPkUserUsername`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, the distinct is being applied on the query not on the mapping phase, as you can see [@Query doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) the annotation only executes jpql queries so a native distinct.

As you say other option to execute a distinct is 
[Spring data Distinct](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

You cannot apply "Distinct" to objects, but you can map then on Set's to avoid duplicated, but the better approach is filter properly the data on the database.

Comment: indeed, but why does it work? I thought it is smart enough to check the key or I don't know, I'm returning a FLeetName list filtered by Distinct keyword

Comment: It work's because you are doing "SELECT DISTINCT u.pk.fleet.fleetName", this sentence is removing all the duplicated strings so the resultset don't contain any duplicity, after that when this resultset is mapped to objects yo have your non repeated string list. You have to think on how works the process of query for an object. Firstly the SQL query is executed, after that with the result set data spring data or other orm or smilar maps the data to Objects or entities.

Comment: Spring data has a lot of magic to star with, but if think in jdbc query everything fits

Comment: Sorry i miss something, of course fleetName is an object, not a string as i post before, but also i's must be an entity and has a primary key, the distinct is checking the primary keys

Comment: yes, it's an object therefore I didn't understand your explanation. I also thought that the check is on the primary key but I didn't find any information online.

Comment: Ok, first things first, you have a dataset on your database with duplicated fleetNames. If you execute your query from a sql client you will get a subset of fleetNames which match your query, this is the ResultSet of the query. Now you want to map that ResultSet to objects, you took every row and construct an object with the value of each column on his properties. here you have done to steps. 1 - Query the data from your database and 2 - Map the data into objects. You are executing a SQL query with distinct so your ResultSet don't contain any duplicated row for step 2

Comment: On Step 2 you only map your row into objects, you don't do any check about distinct because you already had done this part with your Sql Query

Comment: Your JpqlQuery is equivalent to SELECT DISTINCT a.id_fleetName from fleet a INNER JOIN fleet_has_user b on a.id_fleet = b.id_fleet and b.username = :username , if you execute that on a sql client, what you get ?, you get an unique list of fleetNames for a particular user